# AutoMapper mapping wrong fields for UPPERCASE & underscope

Tags: automapper

Today, when i tried to map from `TBL_TRAN_IN` to `InwardTransactionDto`, the field `Id` in `TBL_TRAN_IN` was mapped to many fields (that ended by `_ID`) in `InwardTransactionDto`. Here are my code

```cs
public class TBL_TRAN_IN : Entity<string>
{
      [NotMapped]
      public override string Id
      {
           get { return TRX_TYPE + "-" + RELATION_NO + "-" + O_CI_CODE + "-" + R_CI_CODE + "-" + TRX_DATE; }
           set { /* nothing */ }
      }

      public virtual string CHECK_CODE { get; set; }

      public virtual string CREATE_FILE_RESULT_FLAG { get; set; }

      public virtual string FILE_NAME_RESULT { get; set; }
      //and some fields below
}
```

```cs
public class InwardTransactionDto : EntityDto<Guid?>
{
      public string MSG_KEY { get; set; }

      public string R_CI_ID { get; set; }

      public string O_INDIRECT_ID { get; set; }
      public string R_INDIRECT_ID { get; set; }
      //and some fields below
}
```

My mapping config

```cs
configuration.CreateMap<TBL_TRAN_IN, InwardTransactionDto>().ForMember(x => x.Id, opt => opt.Ignore()).ReverseMap();
```

After mapped, value of `Id` is mapped to all fields that end with `_ID` in the second class(`R_CI_ID`, `O_INDIRECT_ID`, `R_INDIRECT_ID`). Could anyone help?

Comment: That's the default naming convention kicking in. All you can do is write your own and replace the default. See [this](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/pull/922/files).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank for your solution, Lucian. This issue is fixed by new Name Convention:

```cs
public class NoNamingConvention : INamingConvention
{
    public static readonly INamingConvention Value = new NoNamingConvention();

    public NoNamingConvention()
    {
    }

    public Regex SplittingExpression { get; } = new Regex(".+");

    public string SeparatorCharacter => "";

    public string ReplaceValue(Match match)
    {
        return match.Value;
    }
}
```

And my initializer:

```cs
cfg.DestinationMemberNamingConvention = new NoNamingConvention();
```